# How to determine if each element in an array contains a certain letter by making an array of a wordlist file (swift 2)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I am relatively new to swift. I am attempting to make a program that takes a wordlist (in the form of an array of strings) and removes strings that do not contain a user-chosen letter. So, if the wordlist is ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "date", "endive"] and the user chooses the letter "a" (this is the variable "centerletter"), "apple", "banana" and "date" would be returned, as they **do** contain the letter a. This code works when the array inputted (wordlist) is a standard array like ["apple", "banana"]. However, my actual use for this code is for sorting through every word in the English language, as found in my file "words.txt" (one of the files in my swift project).

I have assigned every word in words.txt (which are separated by a /n) to wordlist as follows (this is the function):

```
func arrayFromContentsOfFileWithName(fileName: String) -> [String]? {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("words", ofType: "txt")

    var fileContents: String? = nil
    do {
        fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return fileContents!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    } catch _ as NSError {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I assign wordlist to the result of arrayFromContentsOfFileWithName("words.txt") as so:

```
var wordlist = arrayFromContentsOfFileWithName("words.txt")
```

Then I crunch wordlist with this code (attempting to take out every word of wordlist that does not contain the user-chosen letter ("a" in my example). This code works on a standard array like ["apple", "banana"], but not on the array made with the function arrayFromContentsOfFileWithName.

```
let centerlet:Character = Character(Array(arrayLiteral: centerletter.text!)[0])
```

// centerlet is the letter the user chooses.

```
    for var i = 0; i < wordlist?.count; i++ {
        if wordlist![i].characters.contains(centerlet) {
            print("I am leaving in \(wordlist![i]) because it contains the center letter")
        } else {
            print("I removed \(wordlist![i]) because it did not have the center letter.")
            wordlist?.removeAtIndex(i)
            }
        }
```

**How can I convert all the words in words.txt into a standard swift array so that I can remove every word in said array that does not contain a certain letter?** Thanks.

Comment: I even tried changing the `if wordlist![i].characters.contains(centerlet) {` line to the more optional `if ((wordlist?[i].characters.contains(centerlet)) != nil) {`. Then it left in every single word, even if it did not contain the user-chosen letter.

Comment: I tried replacing .characters.contains = .containsString, but no luck. This is basically the same thing (.characters.contains = .containsString because I am searching for a 1-character string). I tried this and it still does not work; either all negative or all positive depending on how optional I make the if statement (see my first comment).

Comment: Deleted earlier comment because I figured the same thing :) This seems like a perfect case for Swift's functional-style approach using `.filter` or `.map` to turn one array into another array by returning the results from a closure... Which is basically what Mundi just wrote below while I was typing this...

Comment: Iterate through the array of words backwards: `i = ...count-1; i >= 0; i--`

Comment: Suggest editing question to post the text file, or wherever the wordList & centerLetter come from.

Comment: @mc01 I edited my question. Any chance you could help? Thanks.

Comment: Still not sure what `centerletter` is, or what the array contents actually look like, so same problem.

Comment: Your use of componentsSeparatedByString would work if the words list is a list of words separated by newlines. If not, you'll need different code. We can't tell without knowing what's in your data file.

Comment: @mc01 centerlet is the letter the user chose to filter the results by (so if centerlet is a, as in my example, apple, banana, and date would be returned). Centerlet is always an uppercase letter A-Z.

Comment: @DuncanC they are separated by new lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are removing items in your list while iterating through the list with an index. Modifying a list while enumerating it usually leads to disaster, and often delivers unexpected results.

How about a simple filter?

```
let filteredList = wordlist.filter { !$0.characters.contains(letter) }
```

Comment: How do I use this? Using just what you gave results in incorrect results, and substituting filteredList for wordlist in my code yielded same results as initially.

Comment: `var filteredList = wordlist!.filter { $0.characters.contains(centerlet) == false }`  filtered out nothing

Comment: Mundi's solution is perfect, and very Swift-like. (Voted.) This should be the accepted answer. This code will create a new array, filteredList, that contains the items from wordList that do not contain letter

Comment: Aah! I see what's happening here! My array is not the right type (you are right that this works on a standard array!). Right now, I am making an array from text in a file, each element separated by a line break. Maybe this array is in the wrong format?

Comment: @mc01 What do you mean, without it? I get an error without that "!". But that result sounds good (returning the three words with a). And yes, it removes every element of the array and returns an empty array. I have no clue why!

Comment: I'm an idiot... Put this in same Playground after the original code ... which I didn't notice actually removes the elements that don't contain the `centerlet.` Couldn't figure out why there were only 3 elements! Time well spent, yup...  :P

Answer (score 0):

Not following the syntax of `Character(Array(arrayLiteral: centerletter.text!)[0])`

Where is `centerletter.text!` coming from? As far as I can tell you're creating a single-element array from a single letter, then pulling that letter element back out of the array as a Character. Why exactly?

The following just uses `centerlet = "a"` and it works fine...

```
var wordList = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "date", "endive"]

let centerlet:Character = "a"

for var i = 0; i < wordList.count; i++ {
    if wordList[i].characters.contains(centerlet) {
        print("I am leaving in \(wordList[i]) because it contains the center letter")
    } else {
        print("I removed \(wordList[i]) because it did not have the center letter.")
        wordList.removeAtIndex(i)
    }
}
//results 
I am leaving in apple because it contains the center letter
I am leaving in banana because it contains the center letter
I removed cherry because it did not have the center letter.
I removed endive because it did not have the center letter.
```

Comment: Aah! I see what's happening here! My array is not the right type (you are right that this works on a standard array!). Right now, I am making an array from text in a file, each element separated by a line break. Maybe this array is in the wrong format?

Comment: This is crazy. Swift's filter command is a glove fit for this. See Mundi's answer.

Comment: Actually, Duncan, this works, just not in my exact scenario (thanks mc01, you helped me discover my problem). See the update to my question up top please :).

Comment: @mc01 Yeah (my fault), so any idea how I can fix my new problem? Please look at my update to question up top.

Comment: This code will not work correctly because you are removing items from the array and messing up the array indexes. (It will appear to work but you will skip evaluating some words.) Another problem with this code is that Swift 3.0 is going to remove the C-style `for (;;)` loop, so this code is doomed. If you are going to index though the array you have to index through backwards so you don't mess up the array indexes of the not-yet-evaluated words when you remove a word. But use filter. Really.